# How add date to datagridview from column from sql lite database?

Tags: c#

When I use this C# code:

`dataGridView2.Columns["sql_col_name"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"` ,

the datagridview cell written in it is not the date but `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"`

where's the error ??

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set column's `DataType` to `DateTime`. The default `DataType` is set to string.

Are you sure that the format `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"` is correct? Maybe you mean `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss.fff"`?

```
dataGridView2.Columns["sql_col_name"].DataType = typeof(DateTime);
dataGridView2.Columns["sql_col_name"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss.fff";
```